# Using the weight argument with cv.glmnet: how are weights rescaled to sum to N?

Tags: r, glmnet

After performing multiple imputation with PMM and chained equations (M=30), I am attempting to use cv.glmnet() with the weights argument. I am using individual-level weights to address both the differing levels of predictor missingness among participants prior to imputation and the artificially inflated sample size from the imputations. Weights are individual-level, defined as `w = {proportion of non-missing predictors for that individual}/M`. In other words, with M=30 imputations, the weights across an individual's M=30 entries sum to `{proportion of non-missing predictors of that individual}`. Here is the model call:

```
lasso_mod <- cv.glmnet(predictors, mi_derived$outcome, weights=mi_derived$w,
                   family="binomial", nfolds=10, alpha=1, foldid=mi_derived$k, standardize=FALSE)
```

I am choosing not to standardize predictors, as I already standardized prior to imputation (see Wan et al. 2015 *Variable selection models based on multiple imputation with an application for predicting median effective dose and maximum effect* for justification). Regardless, I obtain the same issues described below whether I standardize or not.

My model call selects 90% of predictors, despite models on individual imputations selecting only 20-40% of predictors. Furthermore, I get identical results between model calls with weights as defined above and with weights defined as `{proportion of non-missing predictors of that individual}`.

I understand that *glmnet* automatically re-scales the inputted weights to sum to the sample size N. How exactly does *glmnet* scale these inputted weights to sum to N? I am concerned that this re-scaling is the source of my unexpected results - both too many predictors chosen and the identical results between calls with distinct weights.